# What to name a structure contains hash table and vectors?

Tags: naming-conventions

Here is an easy question:
I have a struct which contains two hash tables and one vector. Im looking for a generic name for this kind of structure. Any suggestions? say factory?

Comment: Suggestion: pick a name based on purpose of that struct and not of the based on the type of its members

Comment: This seems like a pretty specific data structure. Could you provide us with some more details on its intended usage?

Comment: Say my struct is like:

typedef struct{
   hash_t *file_hash;
   hash_t *chunk_hash;
   vector(const char *) namevec;
} matching_xxx;

The purpose of that struct is do some kind of matching. I will of course include "matching" in name, but it will nice to have an noun after that.

Answer (score 3):

Name it based on what it does. No point in naming based on what it is made up of

Answer (score 1):

MatchingDataObject

Answer (score 1):

You could call it "MatchingTuple" since that is what it appears to be, a tuple of data structures.